# How can i generate a binary code table of a huffman tree?

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, huffman-code

I want to implement an function which gives me a binary code for each char in a huffman tree.

To implement the function i tried traversing the table by using a recursive function. However i don't know how to fill the result the binary code for each char so that the function returns an array of struct with all the chars and binary codes

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i'm not sure i understand. What do you mean by hiding a pointer in a typedef?

Comment: `tree_t` I guess (but that could be a struct also!). Would you mind to provide the definition / typedef of `tree_t` so that we know for sure!

Comment: Ah, the definition of tree_t was given, i will add it in the question

Comment: @Stargateur, sorry I did not want to post to many lines of code straight away. I added the definition of make_tree(). Please if you miss anything I will add it.

Comment: I edit your question with a [mcve], like you see you can copy/paste and this will compile.

Comment: @Stargateur, Thnx for your help so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by making `compute_code_table` recursive, this allows you to easily traverse the tree.

Secondly, it helps for every task or assignment to search online for some sources which explain (in pseudo-code or not) how to do your specific task. In this case, this yields the following explanation:

> To generate a huffman code you traverse the tree to the value you
>   want, outputing a 0 every time you take a lefthand branch, and a 1
>   every time you take a righthand branch. (normally you traverse the
>   tree backwards from the code you want and build the binary huffman
>   encoding string backwards as well, since the first bit must start from
>   the top).
>
> [siggraph.org](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html)

In C, this could be implemented as such:

```
int compute_code_table_for_node(tree_t tree, node_t target_node, node_t current_node, int code_table) {
    // Check for target
    if ( current_node == target_node ) {
        // Found target
        return code_table;
    }

    // Check if end-node
    if ( current_node->left == NULL && current_node->right == NULL ) {
        // Is an end node
        return -1;
    }


    // Try left
    int left = compute_code_table_for_node(tree, target_node, current_node->left, code_table << 1 + 0);

    // Try right
    int right = compute_code_table_for_node(tree, target_node, current_node->right, code_table << 1 + 1);

    // Find which path was taken
    if ( left == -1 ) {
        // Left path didn't find it, so it must be the right path:
        return code_table << 1 + 1;
    } else {
        // Left path found it
        return code_table << 1 + 0;
    }
}
```

Then you only have to call `compute_code_table_for_node(tree, node, tree->head, 0)` for every `node` in the `tree`.

This piece of code won't work for your specific case, so you will have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's see a possible solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct code {
    size_t code_length;
    uint32_t code;
} code;

void compute_code_table(tree_t node, code *t, code c) 
{
    if (node->left == NULL) 
        t[node->letter] = c;
    else {
        c.code_length++;
        c.code <<= 1;
        compute_code_table(node->left, t, c);
        c.code += 1;
        compute_code_table(node->right, t, c);
    }
}

void code_print(code *c)
{
    size_t n = c->code_length;
    while (n --> 0)
        putchar('0' + ((c->code >> n) & 1));
}

int main(void)
{
    tree_t root = fixed_tree();
    code table[256] = { 0 };
    code c = { 0 };
    compute_code_table(root, table, c);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if (table[i].code_length) {
            printf("%c\t", i);
            code_print(table + i);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the idea is to have a table which is filled at every leaf. While doing the recursion we pass the current node, the table and the current code. If we are at a leaf we just store the code in the table, otherwise we need to perform the recursion: increase the code length, add a 0 in the least significant bit and do the left branch, then change that 0 to a 1 and do the right branch.